# how to remove characters from variables to remove --function option1 option2

Tags: function, arguments

I created a function to log the results of a script and added an argument to the script. You may look at it at https://docs.laswitchtech.com/doku.php?id=documentations:linux:pxelinux

In this script, I added an argument `--screen` to launch the same script with all the arguments into a screen with the `-L` switch.

```
Enable_Screen(){
    Check_Package screen
    ScreenCMD="./pxelinux.sh"
    CMDOptions="$@"
    CMDOptions=${CMDOptions// --screen/}
    CMD="$ScreenCMD $CMDOptions"
    if [ $debug = "true" ]; then
        echo -e "${ORANGE}[DEBUG][EXECUTE] screen -S PXE_Linux -L $CMD ${NORM}"
    fi
    screen -S PXE_Linux -L $CMD
    mv screenlog.0 pxelinux.screen.log
    exit 0
}
```

Now I would like to add an option to the argument to append the log.

an example of how I execute the script :

```
./pxelinux.sh --debug --screen --install-pxelinux
```

Now this is the example I would like to use

```
./pxelinux.sh --debug --screen append --install-pxelinux
```

Since this is an option for the screen function, I do not want it to be forwarded to the screen I am creating. In the screen function, you can see that I remove the `--screen` from the list of arguments and now I would need to remove `append` as well if it shows up in the arguments. But only if it's in the options of the `--screen` argument. Because `append` is an option to the argument `--screen` and may or may not be enabled.

Basically, I used this convention for my arguments:
`--argument` => execute a function in the script
`argument` => option for the previously stated `--argument`

Put more simply:

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

Config_Network(){
    echo -e "
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address $1
    netmask $2
    gateway $3
" | tee -a /etc/network/interfaces
}

Update_System(){
    Command="apt-get update"; Executing "$Command"
    Command="apt-get upgrade -y"; Executing "$Command"
}

Restart_System(){
    shutdown -r now
}

Check_Package(){
    if [ $(dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' $1 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed") -eq 0 ];
    then
        Command="apt-get install $1 -y"; Executing "$Command"
    fi
}
Executing(){
    if [ $debug = "true" ]; then
        if eval $1;then
            echo -e "${GREEN}[DEBUG  ][$(date)][SUCCESS][EXECUTING] $1 ${NORM}" | tee -a $logfile
        else
            echo -e "${RED}[DEBUG  ][$(date)][ERROR  ][EXECUTING] $1 ${NORM}" | tee -a $logfile
        fi
    else
        if eval $1;then
            echo -e "${GREEN}[DEBUG  ][$(date)][SUCCESS][EXECUTING] $1 ${NORM}"
        else
            echo -e "${RED}[DEBUG  ][$(date)][ERROR  ][EXECUTING] $1 ${NORM}"
        fi

    fi
}
while test $# -gt 0
do
    case "$1" in
        --config-network)
            netconf
            ;;
        --update)
            Update_System
            ;;
        --restart)
            Restart_System
            ;;
        --*) 
            exit
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

exit 0
```

now when I execute script.sh, I want to be able to pass $1 $2 $3 to the netconf fonction no matter where it is in the statement.

```
./script.sh --config-network 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.1 --update --restart
./script.sh --restart --config-network 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.1 --update
./script.sh --update --restart --config-network 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.1 --update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue by testing the following 3 arguments if they contained `--` in them. And since in this case I was looking for IPs and mask, I added a second test for that. So the first `if` validates that the following arguments are not functions in the script and then the second `if` validates the arguments I want to pass to the function.

```
    --config-network)
        if [[ $2 != *--* && $3 != *--* && $4 != *--* ]]; then
            if [[ $2 =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ && $3 =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ && $4 =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                Config_Network $2 $3 $4
            else
                Config_Network
            fi
        else
            echo "Bad [argument] $1 $2 $3 $4"
            Display_Help
            exit
        fi
        ;;
```